# Export Large Lists from SharePoint 2007 C#

Tags: 2007, list, export

I want to create a application to export Large Lists to csv in 2007 where the threshold is 2000 items. 
What is the best approach? i need to export 1.000.000 items in the end.
I know when you delete items you can use batches is this possible by retrieving data as well?

Or should i use the portalsitemap provider or...

Comment: Sigs are discouraged here, see http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to read through all the items once the portalsitemap provider is not going to help you.

The easist is just to read the items using an SPQuery + SPList.GetItems using  [SPListItemCollectionPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemcollectionposition%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to do paging.

I'd sort the items by ID so they can't move while you're reading

Comment: thank you for your reply i am going to look into that.Paul Keijzers @KbWorks

http://www.kbworks.nl http://www.watisoffice365.nl